# How do i get ArcObjects not to ignore a layer definition that has been set?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, vba

I am creating a simple text search application, where the user can enter an address search and the result appear in a listbox, which they can then select it and zoom to the address.

Now the problem I am having is that I have set  layer definition, within the layer I am working with to only show Residential addresses ( and this works, as i can only see residential addresses in the attribute table), however when I enter a street (in the app), that contains not only residential address, the records appear in my list box when though I have set the layer definition.

Is this behavior normal ? and what is the best way to get round this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a normal behaviour.

You can use [IGeoFeatureLayer](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriCarto/IGeoFeatureLayer.htm). It will search only within your definition query.

```
Dim pGeoFtrLyr As IGeoFeatureLayer
Set pGeoFtrLyr = pMap.Layer(0)

Dim pQueryFilter As IQueryFilter
Set pQueryFilter = New QueryFilter
pQueryFilter.WhereClause = "STNAME = 'Stack Street'"

Dim pFtrCur As IFeatureCursor
Set pFtrCur = pGeoFtrLyr.Search(pQueryFilter, False)
```

Or you can simply set set your QueryFilter to include the Layer Definition Query too.